# If Newton’s 3rd law describes a simultaneous force to force reaction then doesn't that imply that force and the resulting velocity are simultaneous?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity

When a force is applied to a particle for a duration of time and we observe the velocity at any instant of that duration Newton’s 3rd law tells us that the force and resulting velocity are simultaneous at that observed instant. This means that, at the instant (t=0) a force is exerted on a particle with zero velocity, the resulting velocity from that force at t=0 is 0.

I’m thinking the force effect on the particle at t=0 is that the particle’s 0 velocity is in a state of change. Without the force the particle is at rest obeying Newton’s 1st law. With the force on the particle at t=0, the particle’s velocity is zero and is changing - in a state of change.

So if force is applied opposite to a particle with a non-zero velocity then its velocity decreases and if we observe when it reaches 0 velocity the force and resulting 0 velocity are simultaneous. This would be identical to instant t=0 above.

When I stand on the floor, gravitational force pushes me onto the floor and the floor simultaneously reacts with an opposite direction matching force. This balance of forces results in a velocity of zero relative to earth’s center. If the floor is removed, my falling velocity is not a reaction to an earlier in time gravitational force. When falling, gravitational force and velocity are simultaneous just as when standing on the floor.

If I walk through a doorway and someone takes a picture of me as I pass through the threshold we don’t say the picture is of a person standing in the doorway. It is a picture of me in motion aligned with the plane of the door threshold at that instant. If someone was pushing me then we would have to include the quantity of acceleration to my motion of that instant in time and threshold plane position.

Now does the force from the pushing at that threshold-position-instant create some velocity of me in the future? Of course not. The pushing force and the reaction force are simultaneous. Why wouldn't the velocity be simultaneous? Why would there be a delay between this force now and the resulting velocity from the force?

Newton’s 3rd law clearly states the reaction from force is simultaneous. If I’m being pushed through the doorway, at any instant observed of the pushing we have force and equal opposite direction reaction force and simultaneous velocity.

Comment: "Newton’s 3rd law tells us that the force and resulting velocity are simultaneous at that observed instant." I never heard of this and don't understand. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: From Wikipedia - Newton’s 3rd law: “if one object A exerts a force FA on a second object B, then B simultaneously exerts a force FB on A,”. “Simultaneously exerts” describes an instant in time where a force and a reaction force exist. If the force FA persists the same simultaneous FA-FB forces exist at any later instant. The velocity, zero or non-zero, at any later instant is simultaneous to FA-FB. We know V changes with time but at any instant observed it is simultaneous to the force applied at that instant.

Comment: If the velocity is the result/reaction of a force from an earlier instant in time then which instant in time of the force is it? You see there is only one conclusion, that force and velocity are simultaneous and I think Newton’s 3rd agrees with that. The force now is not creating a velocity later.

Comment: When I stand on the floor gravitational force pushes me onto the floor and the floor simultaneously reacts with an opposite direction matching force. This is a balanced force that results in a velocity of zero relative to earth’s center. If the floor is removed, my falling velocity is not a reaction to an earlier in time gravitational force. When falling, gravitational force and velocity are simultaneous just as when standing on the floor.

Comment: I agree with Young Kindaichi ... I also don't see a question in your reply.  Can you be much more concise?

Comment: Thanks @David White. The question is - “Doesn't Newton’s 3rd law of motion describe the simultaneity of force and velocity?” My reply is in support of the answer being yes, which is what I think.

Comment: Bill N gave a good answer.  Newton's 3rd law says nothing about velocity.  When you push on a wall, it pushes back, but it doesn't move.

Comment: You are missing the key word "change". As in "change in velocity" as a result of force applied over time.

Comment: Thanks @JAlex. Yes, a force over time changes a velocity. Let’s say a force is exerted over time on a particle and the particle’s velocity is increasing. In the future, at some instant in time, the particle’s velocity is 5 mps. The force on the particle exists at that instant. Does this force, at that instant, result in the particle velocity of 5 mps or does this force, at that instant, have an effect on a future velocity of the particle? I think that since this force and velocity 5 mps are simultaneous and force effects velocity, this force results in the simultaneous 5 mps velocity.

Comment: @JAlex. Also, if the force ceased before the particle velocity reached 5 mps then the particle velocity would be what it was at the last instant the force existed. That satisfies this simultaneity rule and is in line with Newton’s 3rd law of the instantaneous effect of a force exerted on a particle.

Comment: The force at any instant affects the _future_ behavior of the particle. In the world of simulation the current position and velocity are the "state" of the particle, and forces describe how the "state" evolves over time.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been struggling with. When we observe an instant in time of a particle with a velocity we consider its state of motion by position and velocity only. I think we also have to include acceleration as a “state” of its motion. If a force exists then its velocity is in a state of change (being accelerated). If we include this “state” of motion then we don't have to try to say the force now only has an effect on a future velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's 3rd Law tells us nothing about velocity. It tells us that forces are due to interactions of pairs of objects. If object A interacts with object B, then if the force on A because of the interaction is magnitude $F$ in direction $+\hat{n}$, there is, *simultaneously* a force on object B of magnitude $F$ in direction $-\hat{n}$.

That's all it says. Combined with the concepts from Newton's 1st and 2nd Laws we can determine how systems of multiple objects may exchange momenta and change positions.

Comment: Thanks @Bill N. No mention of velocity but we all know velocity is effected by force. When? I think at the instant of the interaction and if the applied force persists then at any instant thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's third law and forces in general have nothing to do with your question.

According to what I've understood, you are asking:

If at a given instant a particle has velocity $\vec v$ and a non-zero acceleration $\vec a$, how can we describe it's velocity at that instant if it is in a "state of change"? Isn't the acceleration changing the velocity at that instant itself?

Taking a page out of 3b1b, the idea of change in an instant is an oxymoron, and it could be helpful to think about the change taking place in some small amount of time $dt$. When the floor between you and the earth is suddenly removed, the only force acting on you now is gravity. But at the moment at which the floor was removed, your velocity was $0$. Now for your velocity to increase by some amount $d\vec v$, gravity needs to act on you for some time $dt$. Now think about what happens as this time $dt$ approaches zero. You reach closer and closer to the answer to "what is happening to the velocity in an instant?". The idea of "state of change" essentially vanishes for unimaginably small amounts of time, as all that is left is the state of the object at the instant.

Also, realistically speaking, force or acceleration is not instantaneous; it has a rate of change called jerk, which can't be infinite. What is simultaneous is the force and the reaction force between two objects, such that one cannot say which was initiated first.

Comment: Thanks @Reet Jaiswal. If we say that the “state of change” of the velocity vanishes for unimaginably small amounts of time then realize that we would have to say the same thing for change of position (velocity). If the particle has a velocity then we know that, no matter how short the time down to an instant in time, the particle is in a state of changing position. Why would we not be able to claim the same thing for an acceleration of the velocity? No reason not to. Acceleration is an instantaneous state of motion just like velocity.

Comment: I agree with you that you can't say which was initiated first. What you also can't say is if this pairing of forces has a history. If the velocity is zero, who’s to say whether the initial force wasn’t applied a second earlier and opposite to a non-zero velocity of the particle? So at this observed instant in time we have zero velocity that was actually non-zero an infinitely short duration in time earlier. Newton’s 3rd law describes simultaneous force reaction-force. The particle begins its change in velocity at the instant of the force and is changing at any instant thereafter.

Comment: @Nectac In reply to your first comment, yes, we would have to apply the same reasoning to the rate of change in position as well. But you must reconsider the notion that a particle with non-zero velocity that is in a state of motion somehow doesn't have an absolute position. Just because the acceleration is non-zero and the velocity is changing doesn't mean we can't determine the velocity at a certain instant; similarly a particle with some velocity still has a definite position at a particular instant. The "state of change" or "state of rest" isn't inherently a property of the particle,...

Comment: ...but a property of the observer's frame of reference AND the particle. Move to a different frame and the particle's state of motion may change; it's relative. Position is relative too, but that doesn't deny the fact that at a particular instant, there exists a singular definite position of the particle and no other. For a rigid body or particle at rest, there's nothing 'special' about a force suddenly acting on it that ties itself to its "state of motion", its position is just changing now in an accelerated manner. So it's not like the particle at an instant has some 'eagerness' to change...

Comment: ...its position, it's just doing so as a virtue of it's pre-existing motion. So when you observe a particle at a certain instant with velocity $\vec v$, it's not in a 'state of changing position'- that's not a property it possesses as I stated earlier, nor is it changing its position at that instant; it is just changing its position by an amount $d\vec r$ in some time $dt$, and $\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$ approaches the instantaneous velocity for smaller and smaller values of $dt$. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: Strangely this question was close because it needs details or clarity while we understand and are discussing the details. Anyways, I believe in absolute position and if there is a velocity relative to that position we have something changing position. When we observe the particle at an instant in time we are not stopping time. Just because the observed instant does not have a duration of time does not mean that time is not flowing and that the particle is not moving.  …..

Comment: If I walk through a doorway and someone takes a picture of me as I pass through the threshold we don’t say the picture is of a person standing in the doorway. It is a picture of me in motion aligned with the plane of the door threshold at that instant. If someone was pushing me then we would have to include the quantity of acceleration to my motion of that instant in time and threshold plane position.  …..

Comment: Now does the force from the pushing at that threshold-position-instant create some velocity of me in the future? Of course not. The pushing force and the reaction force are simultaneous. Why wouldn't the velocity be simultaneous? Why would there be a delay between this force now and the resulting velocity from the force?  ....

Comment: Newton’s 3rd law clearly states the reaction from force is simultaneous. If I’m being pushed through the doorway, at any instant observed of the pushing we have force and equal opposite reaction force and simultaneous velocity.